# Props in custom components React native + Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-native-textinput, react-native-component

I've got a problem with access to onChangeText in my custom component.
Here is the code of my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import {TextInput, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

type Props=
{
   style:any
   
}

const Input = (props:Props) =>
{
    return <TextInput {...props} style = {{...styles.input, ...props.style}} blurOnSubmit autoCorrect = {false} keyboardType = "number-pad" maxLength = {2} />
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    
    input:{
        height:30,
        borderBottomColor: 'grey',
        borderBottomWidth: 1,
        marginVertical: 10
    }
        

})

export default Input;`
```

And here is the part of code in another file where i'm using it:

```
 <Input style = {styles.input} onChangeText = {numberInputHandler} value = {enteredValue} />
```

OnChangeText is underlined and the error is Property 'onChangeText' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Props'. I see in a tutorial that after typing {...props} in my custom component inside  there is access to its props, but guy is writing in js and I'm in in ts. Thanks for help!

Answer (score 8):

Your `Input` component passes through all of its props to the underlying `TextInput`, so you probably want it to accept all of the props that the `TextInput` does.  Right now it only accepts the prop `style` since that is the only property in `Props`.

The props that you want are exported from react-native as `TextInputProps`, so you can import that `interface`.

```
import { TextInput, TextInputProps, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
```

`TextInputProps` already includes a property `style` with a type that's much more accurate than your `any`, so you can delete your `Props` interface entirely.

```
const Input = (props: TextInputProps) => {
```

You'll now get an error when combining the two styles because `props.style` could be an array of styles.  With react-native you can join multiple styles in an array, even when those styles could themselves be an array.  So you can combine like this:

```
style={[styles.input, props.style]}
```

Since we allowed all of the `TextInputProps`,you won't get an error if you call your `Input` with `<Input maxLength={5}/>`.  Right now, that `maxLength` prop would be ignored and overwritten by `maxLength={2}` because of the order -- later props override earlier ones.  If that is what you want, then this component is fine:

```
const Input = (props: TextInputProps) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      {...props}
      style={[styles.input, props.style ]}
      blurOnSubmit
      autoCorrect={false}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      maxLength={2}
    />
  );
};
```

If you want custom props to override the default props, then you would want to change the order:

```
const Input = (props: TextInputProps) => {
  return (
    <TextInput
      blurOnSubmit
      autoCorrect={false}
      keyboardType="number-pad"
      maxLength={2}
      {...props}
      style={[styles.input, props.style]}
    />
  );
};
```

Comment: Excellently written!

Answer (score 3):

You can use custom props as well as TextInput Props in the combine, please refer to the code below,

```
import { TextInput, TextInputProps } from 'react-native';

interface OwnProps {
  style?: ViewStyle;
  password?: boolean;
  error?: string;
}

export type CustomInputProps = TextInputProps & OwnProps;

export const CustomInput = (props: CustomInputProps) => {
    const { style, password, error, ...restProps } = props;
    return (
      <TextInput
        secureTextEntry={password ? hidePassword : false}
        {...restProps}
      />
     );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to tell Typescript that in props there is a function called 'onChangeText', so you have to add it to your Props type:

```
type Props=
{
   style:any
   onChangeText: Function
}
```